# How to specify MS visual studio version for nexe?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, binary

I'm trying to compile my node.js project into a binary using [nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe). I only have Microsoft Visual studio 2012, so the compiler complains it can't find MSVS2010

```
error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found.
```

In [nexe's requirement section](https://github.com/crcn/nexe#requirements), it does mention MSVS2012 can be supported, so I'd like to figure out a way to specify MSVS version.

I tried --msversion=2012 as in [NPM installation](http://kevgriffin.com/specifying-visual-studio-version-in-npm-installs/) but no luck.

Appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: the option is "--msvs_version" so did you maybe just spell it wrong?  

I know this was asked a while ago but I had this same issue and found this page via Google search so maybe this will help someone else in the future